# dkim=temperror (no key for signature)

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

I use BlueHost hosted email and Gmail to actually send the emails via a "Send As" address. I've generated a DKIM 2048 length key, and updated my DNS records accordingly - two DKIM records due to length.

When I send a test  email, the mail goes to Spam immediately. Analyzing the message headers, DKIM fails with error:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
 dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@domain.com header.s=default header.b=JZ1M0o13;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
 dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@domain.com header.s=default header.b=JZ1M0o13;
```

The strange part is my selector is "mail", not "default" - it seems that my DKIM record is not being recognized?

My SPF and DMARC records pass without issue.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: I would suggest to use 1024 bit since 2048 is not always Supported

Comment: Moreover Dig your Domain TXT and the related sub-domain i also suggest to modify the Header to may instead force and enable the test flag sometimes it helps

Comment: The selector mismatch sounds like the problem, investigate why the signed mail apparently says "default" if your intention is for it to be "mail".

Comment: @djdomi - I updated the key to 1024 bit, but DKIM is now returning a status of "fail", but doesn't specify why it's failing. I verified that the DKIM config is valid with MXtoolbox.